# Trying to connect to ASPX site using CURL?

Tags: php, curl, authentication, .aspxauth

I am trying to log into this url:

```
http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx
```

The two fields that are being submitted are labelled:

```
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInEmail
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal
```

The code I've tried to use so far:

```
$username     = 'XXXXXXX';
$password     = 'XXXXXXX';

$loginUrl     = 'http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx';
$cookie  = 'cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); //access login page

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInEmail'] = $username;
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal'] = $password;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);//Get result after login page.

print $ret;
```

This however only takes me back to the original login page... not even with an error message.

I then had a look at what is getting posted, and I saw:

```
Request URL:http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2596
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:VISITORID=9840A7E31683480CB19A66FB8AA73BFC; ASP.NET_SessionId=foous3ftij3os2vvr1wbm3mm; __utma=160092839.590473234.1362995010.1362995010.1362995010.1; __utmc=160092839; __utmz=160092839.1362995010.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _SUPERFLY_nosample=1; shopperName=; signin=0; kalahariShopperId=922859656760417F99E83D5B1427115F; surfLang=ENG; prefLanguage=en-ZA; _chartbeat2=1yx62ww1m7xz1o84.1360134968807.1363000295875.00000000000001
Host:www.kalahari.com
Origin:http://www.kalahari.com
Referer:http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWDQLsuI7QDgKnpLoxApD7nfEPAvLAqqUGAp35/akJAqGiqqYPAsXC5NUHAsHJ5OMCAovxoc8LArq0mqAKApm+rVoC9dLe0Q8C5IvEsAlYqPIdcrZvBZcvYav7ATMf4Nhbfg==
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInEmail:XXXXXXXXX
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal:Password
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPassword:XXXXXXXXXXX
ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$btnSigninTop:Sign in
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtEmail:Email address
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$rdlPasswordYes:rdlPasswordYes
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtPasswordTextNormal:Password
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtPassword:
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$hdnEmailDefault:Email address
ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$hdnPasswordDefault:Password
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Content-Length:146
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 11 Mar 2013 11:11:57 GMT
Etag:
Location:/marketplace/default.aspx
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Set-Cookie:.KALAHARINETAUTH=782A6F442823F8148FB113BA0BAF3A9A8DE253762A4ACFAA5E911E4721166F0EEC6A1891755133AADD28654CF0DAE3880CC2B84260F0B915C07897909CFB071495AF8EF05D1BD678DEE1933FCB08E5ECB1CF76462900681C7D4AE963C151E3079D95FBAD6466F0528787455A951D5EC0DA26F0E6CAA341E4C717D7F3BC01D182F488F47F; domain=.kalahari.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:surfLang=ENG; domain=.kalahari.com; expires=Sat, 11-Mar-2023 11:11:57 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:prefLanguage=en-ZA; domain=www.kalahari.com; path=/
Set-Cookie:signin=1; domain=kalahari.com; path=/
Set-Cookie:tempshopperid=922859656760417F99E83D5B1427115F; domain=kalahari.com; path=/
Set-Cookie:kalahariShopperId=54B14971F72D426BA02DEF3A3D99DC93; domain=kalahari.com; expires=Sun, 17-Jan-2038 22:00:00 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:shopperName=XXXX; domain=kalahari.com; path=/
Set-Cookie:kalahariShopperEmail=XXX@XXXX.XXX; domain=kalahari.com; path=/
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

It looks like I'm supposed to be submitting much more than just the username and password. What exactly must I post and how do I post something like a "viewstate" that isn't a fixed value?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Introduction**

The possible reason why your script is not working are as follows

- Missing `__VIEWSTATE`
- Missing `__EVENTVALIDATION`
- Invalid User Agent
- Using `ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal` for password instead of `ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPassword`
- Incomplete Post Field
- Duplicate Curl Request
- Missing Coolie in Login process

**A Typical server request**

A full long request looks like this

```
POST http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.kalahari.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2584
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.kalahari.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=t2dopenbp5zdfojmg1sd4m55; VISITORID=ECE2335BD47344E29A3D24E04FA31777; mpshopperid=A2E19BEB4D77484A89B9CD64BBB9C294; sign_up_track=sign_up; shopperName=; signin=0; kalahariShopperId=9D0B941AADCC48CA8ACB071C840A9CEB; __utma=46148088.1484253925.1363278451.1363278451.1363278451.1; __utmb=46148088.8.10.1363278451; __utmc=46148088; __utmz=46148088.1363278451.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); surfLang=ENG; prefLanguage=en-ZA; _chartbeat2=fn9a2z0breekvh98.1363278407516.1363278713879.00000000000001

__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEzODYxODcwMTMPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWCAICD2QWBAIDDw8WAh4LTmF2aWdhdGVVcmwFNH4vcGlwZWxpbmUvc2lnbmluLmFzcHg%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%2FwuPOuNOonYg5XWvf3RGR1YVkw%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDQLsuI7QDgKnpLoxApD7nfEPAvLAqqUGAp35%2FakJAqGiqqYPAsXC5NUHAsHJ5OMCAovxoc8LArq0mqAKApm%2BrVoC9dLe0Q8C5IvEsAlYqPIdcrZvBZcvYav7ATMf4Nhbfg%3D%3D&ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInEmail=XXXXXXXXXX%40rmqkr.net&ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal=Password&ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInPassword=XXXXXXXXXX&ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24btnSigninTop=Sign+in&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24txtEmail=Email+address&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24rdlPasswordYes=rdlPasswordYes&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24txtPasswordTextNormal=Password&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24txtPassword=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24hdnEmailDefault=Email+address&ctl00%24ctl00%24cplhMain%24cplhContent%24hdnPasswordDefault=Password
```

**To Use Curl**

```
$url = "http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx";
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";


$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose

/**
    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];



/**
 Start Login process
 */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "";
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInEmail'] = $username;
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal'] = "Password";
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$txtMPTopSignInPassword'] = $password;
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation$btnSigninTop'] = 'Sign in';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtEmail'] = 'Email address';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$rdlPasswordYes'] = 'Password';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtPassword'] = '';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$hdnEmailDefault'] = 'Email address';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$hdnPasswordDefault'] = 'Password';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.

print $ret;
```

Tested and works perfectly fine ...

Comment: To add to this, `__EVENTVALIDATION` is deliberately intended to prevent the kind of scraping you are attempting. A new value will be generated whenever anything runs on the server, not just when the whole page renders, which may include changing individual drop-down box values for instance.

Comment: @Baba, i tried your code and getting internal error. Should i add the values of hidden field myself or it will get automatically filled on loaded?

Comment: it shows that `__EVENTVALIDATION` value is invalid; @IMSoP is right. but how to solve it ?

Comment: This is awesome!! :D

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give it a try and got your code working, see below. I have some var_dump and comments in the code as to what I am doing.

```
<?php
$username     = 'test@example.com';
$password     = 'example';

$loginUrl     = 'http://www.kalahari.com/marketplace/default.aspx';

//on windows server you need full path or its not even used.
$cookie  = dirname(__FILE__) . '\cookies1.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); //access login page

//check the contents of the cookie file. the sessionID, visitorID and kalaharishooperID should be the same with each refresh.
var_dump(implode('', file($cookie)));

//now get the viewstate from the value
//could be better with regex or anything, but this works.
$content = explode('value="', stristr($ret, 'id="__VIEWSTATE"'));
$viewstate = substr($content[1], 0, strpos($content[1], '"'));
var_dump($viewstate);


//now get the EVENTVALIDATION from the value
//could be better with regex or anything, but this works.
$content = explode('value="', stristr($ret, 'id="__EVENTVALIDATION"'));
$validation = substr($content[1], 0, strpos($content[1], '"'));
var_dump($validation);

//define post fields
    //i removed all fields that are not required for the post
$postfields = array(
    "__VIEWSTATE" => rawurlencode($viewstate),
    "__EVENTVALIDATION" => rawurlencode($validation),
    "ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInEmail" => rawurlencode($username),
    "ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInPasswordTextNormal" => "Password",
    "ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24txtMPTopSignInPassword" => rawurlencode($password),
    "ctl00%24ctl00%24ucMarketPlaceSupportNavigation%24btnSigninTop" => "Sign+in",
);
var_dump($postfields);

    //I created the string myself for the post, else I got an error because we already encoded the variable names.
$p = "";
foreach($postfields as $k=>$v) {
    $p .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
}


//do the new post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);//Get result after login page.

    //this contains 'You have entered an invalid password' so it works as expected.
var_dump($ret);

?>
```

Comment: `rawurlencode()` will result "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."

Answer (score 1):

This is a most likely a CRSF token. You will have the call the page then use the value returned in your logon request. DropBox uses a similar process. If you grab the dropbox uploader script from https://github.com/jakajancar/DropboxUploader/ you can see how it does this.